# C++/CLI: Is overloading on return type only possible?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, overloading

If I understand well, in C#, it is possible to do

```
public class X : ICloneable
{
    public X Clone() { ... }
    object ICloneable.Clone() { return Clone(); } // This calls the above
}
```

according to [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/469671-generic-icloneable). This kind of overloading is forbidden in C++, since it only depends on the return type.

Now, I would like to do this exact thing with `ICloneable` in C++/CLI. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of overloading is allowed in C# not because of different return type, but because of explicit implementation of interface - `ICloneable.Clone`.

About C++/CLI look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235235%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: yep, I had to find out it is called "explicit override".

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way:

```
public ref class X : public ICloneable
{
    virtual System::Object^ Clone2() sealed = ICloneable::Clone;
public:
    X(X const&); // Traditional C++ copy constructor
    X^ Clone();
};

System::Object^ X::Clone2() { return this->Clone(); }
X^ X::Clone() { return gcnew X(*this); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can just leave out the second line, C++ allows covariance in overrides.  Since `X Clone()` is compatible with the contract for `object ICloneable::Clone()`, it can put it directly into the v-table without needing a forwarding function.

Comment: are you sure ? Those are two different methods actually.